# How do I get this shelf off my wall, no screws showing

Tags: shelving

[image]

This wall rack does not have any screws showing  in the i

Any ideas of how to get it off the wall?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried sliding it up on the wall? Mounts where the screwed in braket is hidden often involve pushing the shelf onto a mount then sliding it down to lock it in place

Comment: @Jaydles Way to go Jaydles! Who knew you about that stuff.

Comment: @bib, I had a good teacher. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Many fixtures with hidden brackets - especially bathroom fixtures - are secured with a set screw into each bracket. Check the underside on each end of the shelf for a small screw. These are usually slotted or hex screws, usually no more than 1/2" in length. You may need to back the screw out almost all the way, as there is sometimes a lip it has to clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  It was the tiny hole and was a spring release so it took a bit of coordination but we got it off!!  WooHoo!!  Thanks again